# Logging prepared sql statements in postgres jdbc driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I want to log all prepared sql statements in my java application. I'm using the standard postgres jdbc driver org.postgresql.Driver. This driver has a parameter called "
loglevel"  which can be set to 1 (INFO) or 2 (DEBUG). The point is if the parameter is set to 1 it's almost logging nothing, if set to 2 it's tracing too much like

```
...
20:59:05.608 (2)  FE=> Bind(stmt=null,portal=null,$1=<'5'>,$2=<'13'>)
20:59:05.609 (2)  FE=> Describe(portal=null)
20:59:05.609 (2)  FE=> Execute(portal=null,limit=1)  
20:59:05.609 (2)  FE=> Sync
20:59:05.648 (2)  <=BE ParseComplete [null]
20:59:05.649 (2)  <=BE BindComplete [null]
20:59:05.649 (2)  <=BE NoData
20:59:05.649 (2)  <=BE CommandStatus(UPDATE 1)
...
```

Is there a way to only log the statements + parameters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're lucky that you're using PostgreSQL. The `PreparedStatement` implementation of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver (at least, since 8.x or something) has its [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) overridden that way so you could see the entire SQL statement with all parameters filled in the right places. So you could just do something like:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, value1);
preparedStatement.setString(2, value2);
// ...
logger.debug(preparedStatement); // Will show entire SQL with all values.
```

*(where `logger` is just your logger, e.g. slf4j/logback or something)*

Comment: I'm not seeing this in the 9.1 version of the driver.

Comment: Works for me with 9.3.

Comment: If you have access to the application code, yes. Any idea how to log the statement for third-party code that you cannot change (but configure logging)?