# Is it possible to use a Prepared Statement in Java when creating a database schema?

Tags: java, sql, database, prepared-statement

If not, is there a safer way than String concatenation?

Tried this ..

```
final String CREATE_SCHEMA_SQL = "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ?";
List<String> schemas = // ["001", "002", "003"];

for (String schema : schemas) {

  try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
      PreparedStatement createSchemaStatement =
          connection.prepareStatement(CREATE_SCHEMA_SQL)) {

    createSchemaStatement.setString(1, schema);
    createSchemaStatement.executeUpdate();
    
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not create tenant schema");
  }
}
```

Produces this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 29
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2674)
```

Comment: are the schemas user supplied? If they are fixed strings you supply you also know that concatenation is no issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43384505/995891 is the issue I think

Comment: Apparently you can call `toString` on a Postgres `PreparedStatement` and see what its rendered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195855/logging-prepared-sql-statements-in-postgres-jdbc-driver

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17648861/can-we-use-ddl-commands-in-a-prepared-statement-postgresql

Comment: Even if you're sanitizing your input, in general, this screams security vulnerability...

Answer (score 1):

There are some constraints when a dynamic value is passed through a query and then the query is translated to be executed in database. Most database drivers do expect dynamic parameters only in specific places for security reasons as for example a dynamic parameter after the `where` clause, or after `values` in an insert script. The certain is that `postgresql` and most other drivers as well don't expect a dynamic parameter in the SQL for the creation of a schema.

String concatenation in `SQL` creation is known as bad practice as it could lead to some security issues, since all drivers expect the `SQL` passed to be static and safe while parameters are dynamic and are always checked if they contain something malicious. For this reason I would propose to avoid String concatenation to solve this issue and check the following approach.

Create the following function in your postgresql database.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_custom_schema(s_name text) RETURNS void AS $$
        BEGIN
            EXECUTE 'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS' || quote_ident(s_name);
        END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So we now have a function to do the job which accepts as parameter the schema name. Now the database driver would have no problem to accept a dynamic parameter for schema name and translate it correctly before executing the script.

Just note that functions are executed by the use of a subinterface of [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) which is the [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html).

So your code now will be

```
    final String CREATE_SCHEMA_SQL = "{call create_custom_schema(?)}";
    List<String> schemas = // ["001", "002", "003"];
    
    for (String schema : schemas) {
    
      try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
          CallableStatement createSchemaStatement = connection.prepareCall(CREATE_SCHEMA_SQL)) {
    
           createSchemaStatement.setString(1, schema);
           createSchemaStatement.executeQuery();
        
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create tenant schema");
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using dynamic SQL on the server side, you could query the create statement using PostgreSQL's [format function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to encode the identifier.

For example:

```
private String getCreateSchemaStatement(Connection conn, String schemaName) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT format('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS %I', ?)";
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        stmt.setString(1, schemaName);
        return getSingleResultString(stmt);
    }
}

private String getSingleResultString(PreparedStatement stmt) throws SQLException {
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        String result = null;
        if (rs.next()) {
            result = rs.getString(1);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Having this, you can just execute the statements:

```
public void createSchemas(List<String> schemaNames) throws SQLException {
    try (Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
        for (String schemaName : schemaNames) {
            String sql = getCreateSchemaStatement(conn, schemaName);
            stmt.execute(sql);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is not needed if the schema names are known to be safe.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.